# Can you call a Netezza stored procedure more than once in Select?

Tags: sql, netezza

I created a simple stored procedure for testing purposes in Netezza that returns a string. When I call it from a select statement, it works fine, unless I call it more than once on multiple columns. I get the error:

> ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Can't use a stored procedure in this context.

Is this not allowed?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEST_PROC(VARCHAR(ANY))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
    TEST_PAR ALIAS FOR $1;

BEGIN

RETURN 'A' || TEST_PAR;

END;
END_PROC;
```

How I call it:

```
SELECT SP_TEST_PROC('abc') as test1, sp_test_proc('def') as test2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call more than one stored procedure in a SELECT. There are a couple of ways that you can call a Netezza stored procedure:

```
CALL SP_TEST_PROC('abc');
EXEC SP_TEST_PROC('abc');
SELECT SP_TEST_PROC('abc');
```

However, the you cannot have a FROM clause when using SELECT. The SELECT form is just a synonym for one of the other forms, and is not really a SELECT as we would normally think of one.

You can find the documentation on calling a stored procedure [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_how_to_execute.html).

If you are looking for a scalar function, then you are probably better served by writing a UDF.  However, UDFs in Netezza do not support NZPLSQL as a language. You would have to write it in one of the supported UDF languages (e.g C++ or Lua).

Answer (score 0):

To execute a stored procedure you must run this command:

```
EXECUTE SP_TEST_PROC('abc')
EXECUTE SP_TEST_PROC('def')
```

and not as you've written:

```
SELECT SP_TEST_PROC('abc') as test1, sp_test_proc('def') as test2
```

You can go [here](http://www.dataplatformexperts.com/writing-stored-procedure-in-netezza/) for an example

Comment: "SELECT SP_TEST_PROC('abc') as test1" works, I guess it's just converting it to an EXECUTE statement